# jsPlumb unnable to connect mutiple points

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I'm trying to use jsPlumb, version 1.4.1 with the jquery dependency, to  bind some divs in my UI together.

My initial code:

```
jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {
        var eclipse = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("java-eclipse");
        var netbeans = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("java-netbeans");

        jsPlumb.connect({
            source:eclipse,
            target:netbeans,
            connector:"Straight",
            paintStyle:{ lineWidth:5, strokeStyle:'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)' },
            endpoint:"Dot",
            anchor:[ "Perimeter", { shape:"Circle" }]
        });
     });
```

Which works as intended, but as soon as I try to add more end points to make another connection:

```
//Innitial working endpoints
var eclipse = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("java-eclipse");
var netbeans = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("java-netbeans");

//Just adding these endpoints causes my script to crash
var javaSE = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("java-se");
var javaSW = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("java-sw");
```

This gets me the following error:

```
Error: H is undefined
r@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/1.4.1/jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.1-all-min.js:1:9455
```

I have no idea why the second set of endpoints I create causes the whole thing to crash, the divs exist and have the right ids and looking at the js plumb demos and docs making two separate connections (se->sw and eclipse->netbeans) should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
jsPlumb.connect({
        source:eclipse,
        target:netbeans,
        connector:"Straight",
        paintStyle:{ lineWidth:5, strokeStyle:'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)' },
        endpoint:"Dot",
        anchor:[ "Perimeter", { shape:"Circle" }],
        maxConnections: -1
    });
```